# SQL Insert Update Issue in Procedure

Tags: stored-procedures

This is my first post to this website.
Here is my question: I want to use the same stored procedure for Insert and Update.

For Insert there is no problem. But at the time of update O want to update it based on my primary key, not on any unique column value.

Here is my current Procedure.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT MemberID FROM MEMBER WHERE MEMBERSHIPNO=@MEMBERSHIPNO)
WHERE MEMBERSHIPNO=@Membershipno
```

I want to use  `WHERE MemberID=@MemberID` //Memberid is primary key

Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand you're question quite clearly, but from what I understand you're trying to do a IF clause that would UPDATE if said credentials exists.

Something like this would do the trick, just fill in the logic and it should all work out.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT MemberID FROM MEMBER WHERE MEMBERSHIPNO=@MEMBERSHIPNO)
    UPDATE [ADD UPDATE LOGIC HERE] WHERE MemberID=@MemberID
ELSE
    INSERT [ADD INSERT LOGIC HERE]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello Sir,your solution is quite helpful. WHERE MemberID=@MemberID  Here I am not accepting  MemberID from user. I want it to retrieve based on select query SELECT MemberID FROM MEMBER WHERE MEMBERSHIPNO=@MEMBERSHIPNO

Comment: Then you would have to do a SELECT INTO statement in order to populate your @MemberID prior to the update call. I don't know if it's possible to do so enclosed in the EXISTS statement, I haven't done SQL in a while I'm quite rusty ;)

Perhaps this would work:

`IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 MemberID FROM MEMBER INTO @MemberID WHERE MEMBERSHIPNO=@MEMBERSHIPNO)`

Hope this helps!